# Server Environment Variables Usage

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I have never really had the need to use server environment variables before. I am able to set them easily and that is not the issue. I have a program that based on the value of the server environment variable, it will determine the volume and several other folders that the program will write a file to. How can I do this effectively? Once I set the variable in the run config how do I reference it in the actual code?

The program is designed to retrieve a jsonRequest and based on that place a pdf file in an appropriate folder. The path I am referring to is the path that the pdf file is placed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by calling [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))

```
String yourname = System.getenv("yourkey");
```

As an alternative you could always use System properties and then them via `-Dname=value` in your command line starting your app.

As you see here, when starting through eclipse, your system environment might still be in place:

[image: options in eclipse]

Comment: First of all thank you. Second, in order for this to run I'm sending a jsonRequest through postman. Would I need to actually run the program through the run option in eclipse for the variable to still be in effect?

Comment: How would I set it up where it could reference the variable without having to use the run environment?

Comment: If your're on windows: By invoking `SET name=value`. On linux it's `export name=value` I think.